# Fetch data from tsv file to javascript using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to fetch data from `tsv` file to `javascript` using `d3`? Below is `pop.tsv` file and I want to total the sum of population:

pop.tsv:

```
month  |  population
-------+-------------
Jan    |  9301
Feb    |  2001
Mar    |  5002
Apr    |  7002
May    |  1243
```

Comment: Thanks in advance......... Any help always be approciated...

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
  <script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  d3.tsv("pop.tsv", function(error, data)
  {
     var tot=0;   
     data.forEach(function(d)
     {
       d.population = +d.population;
       tot = tot + d.population;
     }) 
     document.write("Total Population is "+tot);
   });

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go trough every line, parse `population` to number using `parseInt()` and sum the data:

```
d3.tsv("pop.tsv", function(data) {
    var sum = 0;
    data.forEach(function(d) { 
        sum += parseInt(d.population);
    });
    console.log('total population: ' + sum);
});
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1v46w8wa/

Comment: @ArvindShelke: What is not working? In FF it prints the result in the console.